# CSV upload in postgresql with data modification

Tags: r, postgresql, csv, import-from-csv

I have thousands of huge CSV files that I need to upload into Postgres. I read that `COPY FROM` is the fastest way to upload csv files. However, I need to do a bit of pre-processing of the data. As a bare minimum, I need to add the filename (or some sort of file id) so that I can tie the information to its source.

Right now, I'm reading the CSV files into a R data frame, adding a column with filename to the data frame and then writing the data frame to Postgres using

```
dbWriteTable(con, name = 'my_table', value = my_dataframe, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE, overwrite= FALSE)
```

I want to know if there is a better/faster way of importing the csv files.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. OK, so, have you compared `dbWriteTable` to `COPY FROM` at all in terms of performance on your system? It might be good to benchmark it. You can get answers on which workflows people theoretically think should work better, but the reality is that it's highly empirical in nature -- it will depend on a lot of characteristics specific to your hardware, your R, your Postgres, etc. So at least benchmark the options you know of already.

Comment: A comparable approach is to run a procedure/function in Postgres that loops through filesystem and imports CSVs using command `COPY FROM`.

Comment: @Hack-R `COPY FROM` is about 3 times faster than `dbWriteTable` on the small set I tested, but I'm not sure how to manipulate the data using `COPY FROM` on the fly